# How to find all references of a specific function definition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am interested in **finding** (in the form of line and column position and value) **all references where a specific function has been called inside a Python sourcefile**.

I have looked into the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html) and these [docs](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I have not found a way to achieve my goal. All I am able to do is find the nodes of function definitions and of every call.

Does anyone know how to achieve on getting the references of a specific *function*? Ideally, I would like to do the same for *classes* as well.

Comment: I don't think you can. You could have something like `f = functionA if randomStuff else functionB`, or local variables shadowing functions, and don't even get me started on `eval` and friends...

Comment: @tobias_k I saw that one could do that with libclang in C++ and hoped the same could be done in Python. Then I am very curious how the interpreter then 'knows' which function to call when 'seeing' a source file's AST...

Comment: @Karim: It's not a compile-time thing; functions are resolved at runtime like any other variable.

Comment: @user2357112 I see. Then, now way for someone to programmatically access and resolve such information?

Comment: The interpreter knows which function is currently bound to a variable by... well, _interpreting_ stuff (including stuff in `eval` and `exec`, if any). The interpreter knows which function to call _when_ it has to call it, not sooner. There surely is _some_ static analysis you can do, to find _some_ or maybe even _most_ references to some given function (as some Python IDEs are doing), but IMHO you can not be sure to get them all. Anyway, just wanted to throw in my doubts about the general case.

Comment: 2 possibilities (well, except for the column no).  1 is to add an analysis of the stack trace in your called function.  **inspect.stack()** is the function I found useful.  Another is to use a utility like pycallgraph (or whatever it uses under the cover) and look at the results.  Combine either with a high code coverage ratio and you should be pretty well set.  Static analysis?  The wrong tool for this of question in Python, sorry - you could easily be assigning function references for your tgt function onto various objects/mappings and then calling it from there, that kinda stuff.

Comment: it cannot be done via pure `ast` module. Consider using [`astroid`](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid) to _infer_ whether `Call` node uses function you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

```
<`# this should get you the functions import ast  

def get_function(node):  
    for stmt in node.body:  
        if isinstance(stmt, ast.FunctionDef):  
            print('This is a Function: {}'.format(stmt.name))  
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):  
            print('This is a Class: {}'.format(stmt.name))  

if __name__ == '__main__()':  
    with open('/examples/filename.py').read() as data:  
        tree = ast.parse(data)  
        get_function(tree)
```

`#I believe this should help.`>